# Graph Combinatorics: How many such Graphs are there?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

How many $4$-regular graphs exist on $8$ vertices?

I found that such a graph can't be disconnectd since if so, then graph can be written as disjoint union of atleast two graphs. $4$ regularity condition says that in any component no. of vertices is atleast $5$, so such graph is not possible.

So all graphs will be connected. One such is $K_{4,4}$. How to find rest?

Further how to find those which alongwith above conditions have even Laplacian eigenvalues.

Comment: There are 6 such graphs (up to isomorphism), and pictures of 3 of them at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticGraph.html See http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/REGGRAPHS/08_4_3.html for all six of them.

Comment: @ Gerry Merrison, Can you suggest me combinatorial way to count.

Comment: No, but maybe there's something in the links and references at https://oeis.org/A006820 and https://oeis.org/A033301

Comment: So, find anything useful at those webpages?

Comment: @ Gerry, yes it was helpful for my purpose

Comment: Thank you for references, still I have to work out a bit but got a direction.

Comment: OK. If you figure it all out, I encourage you to write it up and post it here as an answer.